# Updating the URL in TrackPlayer

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

How to update the url in `react-native-track-player`?

The urls I have expire after 3 hours and I would like to be able to update them in case we would like to use the app in the morning and continue the music from where we left.

I tried the following:

1. Get current track index and get the current position
2. Using `remove(index)` to remove the current track from the queue
3. Regenerate the `Track` and add it to the queue using `add()`
4. Seek to the position and playing the track again

The problem I faced with that approch was it didn't really remove the old one, rather just added the new one. And I don't know if it's the best way regarding performance ..

As a requirement, I must have unique tracks in the queue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: queue is maintained using states/props or just an array?

Comment: neither, I don't want to make it too complex. Just before adding the new track, I get all tracks using `getQueue()` and use a unique key on each track to check whether the track exists or not